# Bootstrap4 Responsive Navbar wraps text on resize

Tags: responsive-design, bootstrap-4

New to bootstrap 4 and I am attempting to build a responsive navbar with the following markup:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <title>Test Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style.css">    
</head>
<body> 
 <!-- Navigation Bar -->
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary sticky-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="tel:8005551212">Call Us At (800) 555-1212 For An Appointment</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="navResponsive">
   <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navResponsive">
   <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 1 Test</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 2 Test</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 3 Test</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 4 Test</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 5 Test</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 6 Test</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </nav>
 <!-- End Navigation Bar -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem I am having is on the resize of the browser the menu text wraps.  Is there a way to avoid this?

Also, if I click on the toggle menu, the dropdown does not display.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Your menu has too much text to be displayed on one line at a narrow width... what do you **want** to happen when the user has a smaller window? Do you want the titles to gain ellipsis? Or do you want the dropdown-toggle to kick in at a wider width?

Comment: I figured as much.  I would like to explore both options, if you have them.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing in `data-target` the `#` you need it to assign the toggle to a menu and you assign the id so, it need to be

```
data-target="#navResponsive"
```

for the text wrap problem you can just make `max-width`

```
.navbar .navbar-brand {
    max-width: 80%;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

```css
.navbar .navbar-brand {
    max-width: 80%;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
         <title>Test Website</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style.css">    

         <!-- Navigation Bar -->
         <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary sticky-top">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="tel:8005551212">Call Us At (800) 555-1212 For An Appointment</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navResponsive">
           <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navResponsive">
           <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 1 Test</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 2 Test</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 3 Test</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 4 Test</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 5 Test</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Page 6 Test</a></li>
           </ul>
          </div>
         </nav>
         <!-- End Navigation Bar -->
         <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
         <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
         <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
         <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
```